# JQuery Selector по маске

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть набор элементов, необходимо сделать селектор по началу строки, например все элементы, у которых id начинается с "ar". Как лучше в jQuery это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[API jQuery: Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Все элементы из документа:

```
var elements = $('[id^="ar"]');
```

Если уже есть выборка `selectedElements`, то ищем среди них:

```
var elements = $(selectedElements).find('[id^="ar"]');
```

Answer (score 5):

Что-то в этом духе:

```
    $('[id^="ar"]').each(function(){
      тут что-то делаем...
    })
```

Comment: спасибо за оперативность :)